# MacBook Pro cannot find keyboard and searching for keyboard for 1-2 minutes

Tags: macbook-pro, security, hacking

I never use a wireless keyboard or mouse. I do use a wired keyboard and wired mouse. I've noticed on several occasions when I unplug and move to a different location without those accessories, for a time I loose access to my touchpad and sometimes my keyboard as well. Occasionally, I get the message saying no keyboard found, searching for keyboard. This is a MacBook Pro - it has a keyboard built in. After a minute or 2, my MacBook keyboard starts working.

Any ideas what is happening? Is there any reason to be concerned from a security standpoint? What I can do to prevent this from happening or, if it's a problem with the MacBook, keep it from getting worse?

Message that is displayed is shown below.

[image: Image of Message that displays when MacBook keyboard not usable is below]

Comment: The built in keyboard and trackpad are USB devices and I’ve never seen a Mac search for a USB device.  Can you post a screen shot of your error message?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What is your MacBook Pro model and macOS version?

Comment: MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018), 
2.2 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7, 
macOS Catalina version 10.15.6

Comment: Is bluetooth switched on?

Comment: yes, bluetooth is switch on

Comment: Added screen shot of error message.